# How can I convert a nested xml to a dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a nested xml file . I also have the corresponding xsd file(if required).

How can I convert that into a dataframe using python?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example, i hope it'll help you

file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  
       <Food>
  
           <Info>
           <Msg>Food Store items.</Msg>
           </Info>
  
           <store slNo="1">
               <foodItem>meat</foodItem>
               <price>200</price>
               <quantity>1kg</quantity>
               <discount>7%</discount>
           </store>
  
           <store slNo="2">
               <foodItem>fish</foodItem>
               <price>150</price>
               <quantity>1kg</quantity>
               <discount>5%</discount>
           </store>
  
           <store slNo="3">
               <foodItem>egg</foodItem>
               <price>100</price>
               <quantity>50 pieces</quantity>
               <discount>5%</discount>
           </store>
  
           <store slNo="4">
               <foodItem>milk</foodItem>
               <price>50</price>
               <quantity>1 litre</quantity>
               <discount>3%</discount>
           </store>
  
       </Food>
```

main.py

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
import pandas as pd
  
# give the path where you saved the xml file
# inside the quotes
xmldata = "path/to/file.xml"
prstree = ETree.parse(xmldata)
root = prstree.getroot()
  
store_items = []
all_items = []
  
for storeno in root.iter('store'):
    
    store_Nr = storeno.attrib.get('slNo')
    itemsF = storeno.find('foodItem').text
    price = storeno.find('price').text
    quan = storeno.find('quantity').text
    dis = storeno.find('discount').text
  
    store_items = [store_Nr, itemsF, price, quan, dis]
    all_items.append(store_items)
  
xmlToDf = pd.DataFrame(all_items, columns=[
  'SL No', 'ITEM_NUMBER', 'PRICE', 'QUANTITY', 'DISCOUNT'])
  
print(xmlToDf.to_string(index=False))
```